# Join 2 tables and display by ID

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables :

Table clienti :

```
CodClient | NumeClient | AdresaClient 
_____________________________________
     1    |   cosmin   |   sibiu        
     2    |    alex    |   brasov
```

Table facturi :

```
CodClient | NrFactura  | DataFactura
_____________________________________
     1    |   654321   | 2015-02-21        
     2    |   123456   | 2015-02-22
```

CodClient=the link between the 2 tables.

I have a page with a table containing information from the tables above :

```
 NumeClient | AdresaClient | NrFactura | DataFactura
  cosmin    |    sibiu     |   654321  | 2015-02-21 | Open separate
   alex     |    brasov    |   123456  | 2015-02-22 | Open separate
```

When i click the button Open Separate it takes me to this page where i see each row individualy
Open separate button sends CodClient to this page :

```
<?php
include('connect.php');

$CodClient=$_GET['CodClient'];

$CodClient = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$CodClient);


$rez=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT NumeClient, AdresaClient, NrFactura, DataFactura, FacturaRetea FROM clienti c join facturi f on c.CodClient = f.CodClient");
$rows=mysqli_fetch_array($rez);
?>
```

```
  <div class="factura_header">
    <img src="img/logo2.png">
  </div>

  <div class="factura_stanga">
    <p>Client: <?php echo $rows['NumeClient'];?></p>
    <p>Adresa: <?php echo $rows['AdresaClient'];?></p>
  </div>

  <div class="factura_dreapta">
    <p>Numar factura: <?php echo $rows['NrFactura'];?></p>
    <p>Data Factura: <?php echo $rows['DataFactura'];?></p>
  </div>

  <div class="despartitor">
  </div>

</div>

<?php
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

The problem is that whatever the row i open it shows me the same information.
If i click the first Open Separate it shows me the information with "cosmin sibiu" and if i click the second Open Separate it shows me also "cosmin sibiu", although in browser adress bar i see the corect CodClient.
What am i doing wrong ?
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: in your SQL you're not passing the `$CodClient` id and instead you're simply joining both SQL tables based on generic relationship between attributes ... you need to add something like `SELECT NumeClient, AdresaClient, NrFactura, DataFactura, FacturaRetea FROM clienti c join facturi f on c.CodClient = f.CodClient where c.CodClient = 10 /* this is your $CodClient id from URL*/` ... obviously make sure it's safe from injections, etc.

Comment: awesome, glad it helped! I've added it as an answer to your question, please accept it so that it's resolved & closed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your SQL you're not passing the `$CodClient` id and instead you're simply joining both SQL tables based on generic relationship between attributes ... you need to add something like `SELECT NumeClient, AdresaClient, NrFactura, DataFactura, FacturaRetea FROM clienti c join facturi f on c.CodClient = f.CodClient where c.CodClient = 10 /* this is your $CodClient id from URL */` ... obviously make sure it's safe from injections, etc.